# What is the api to get list of premium storage account vm sizes?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-management-api

What is the api to get list of premium storage account vm sizes?

I don't want to hardcode DS-series, DSv2-series, Fs-series and GS-series VMs that can use Premium Storage

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like there is one. 
rolesizes gives some relevant info regarding cores and memory.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn469422.aspx

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/10/16/a-new-version-of-windows-azure-service-management-api-is-available-with-delete-specific-role-instances-and-more-goodies/

Answer (score 1):

AS far as I know, we can't get the SKU name(or size name) of Azure VM via Azure storage type.
I recommend you can refer to this [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt269440.aspx) to get the Azure VM size and type.
 e.g.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "name": "Standard_A0",
      "numberOfCores": 1,
      "osDiskSizeInMB": 130048,
      "resourceDiskSizeInMB": 20480,
      "memoryInMB": 768,
      "maxDataDiskCount": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Standard_A1",
      "numberOfCores": 1,
      "osDiskSizeInMB": 130048,
      "resourceDiskSizeInMB": 71680,
      "memoryInMB": 1792,
      "maxDataDiskCount": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Standard_A2",
      "numberOfCores": 2,
      "osDiskSizeInMB": 130048,
      "resourceDiskSizeInMB": 138240,
      "memoryInMB": 3584,
      "maxDataDiskCount": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Standard_A3",
      "numberOfCores": 4,
      "osDiskSizeInMB": 130048,
      "resourceDiskSizeInMB": 291840,
      "memoryInMB": 7168,
      "maxDataDiskCount": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "Standard_DS13",
      "numberOfCores": 8,
      "osDiskSizeInMB": 1047552,
      "resourceDiskSizeInMB": 114688,
      "memoryInMB": 57344,
      "maxDataDiskCount": 16
    },
    {
      "name": "Standard_DS14",
      "numberOfCores": 16,
      "osDiskSizeInMB": 1047552,
      "resourceDiskSizeInMB": 229376,
      "memoryInMB": 114688,
      "maxDataDiskCount": 32
    }
  ]
}
```

An alternative approach is that you can filter the VM size supported by Premium Storage with the key words. For instance, you can filter the name included the '`DS`'

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, all premium storage sizes contain 's'.

If you filter the vm size by any containing 's' after 'Standard_' you should get only sizes that support premium storage.